# How to enable and disable an Ajax.Actionlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc razor view:-

```
<div id="link">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sync With IT360 >>", "Sync","TechnologyAudit", 
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "result"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",
 HttpMethod="POST",
 OnBegin="disablelink",
 OnSuccess="enablelink"
}
)
   </div> 
    <p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /></p>
<div id="result"></div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disablelink() {
        $("link").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    };
    function enablelink() {
        $("link").removeAttr("disabled");
    };
</script>
}
```

i am trying to disable the Ajax.Actinolink once click on it (to avoid unnecessary duplicate requests), and then to re-enable it once the call is completed.
the above is not working and the link will not be disabled ?
Can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hide the link, display a loading image.
Once complete, display the link.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sync With IT360 >>", "Sync","TechnologyAudit", 
    new AjaxOptions {
      OnBegin = "$(this).hide()",
      OnComplete = "$(this).show()",
      LoadingElementId = "imgLoading"
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

An ActionLink is effectively just an anchor element. Anchor elements don't support a disabled property a la buttons.

What you can do however, is temporarily remove the href of the anchor element and then re-add it once the request is completed.

Try this:

First, make sure your ActionLink has an id by the using one of the ActionLink overloads that contains the htmlAttributes parameter.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sync With IT360 >>", "Sync","TechnologyAudit",
    new AjaxOptions {
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      UpdateTargetId = "result"  ,
      LoadingElementId = "progress",
      HttpMethod="POST",
      OnBegin="disablelink",
      OnSuccess="enablelink"
    }, new {@id = "ActionLinkId"}
)
```

Update your Javascript to be something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ref = "";

    function disablelink()
    {
        ref = $("#ActionLinkId").attr('href');
        $("#ActionLinkId").attr('href', 'javascript:;')
    };
    function enablelink() {
         $("#ActionLinkId").attr('href', ref)
    };
</script>
```

Further to this, you can also prevent the mouse cursor from reacting to this link while the content is loading using CSS. By having a CSS class similar to this:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You can then add and remove this class to your link inside your two Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you have to have a `#` in front of the ID: `$("#link")`

But I'm not so sure you can disabled a `div` like this. What you can do is create a second tag, like a `<span>`.

```
<span id="linktext">Sync With IT360 >></span>
```

And have it hidden

```
#linktext { display: none; }
```

Then show and hide the two depending on the state

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disablelink() {
        $("#link").hide();
        $("#linktext").show();
    };
    function enablelink() {
        $("#link").show();
        $("#linktext").hide();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: but i do nto want to hidd the link, i just to make it disabled and un-clickable..

Comment: The effect on the user is the same: you hide the link, and show some text that looks like the link, but can't be clicked. Then when you want to make it clickable again, hide the text and show the link.

Comment: If you need to, you can use CSS to style the text to look like a link `#linktext { text-decoration: underline; color: blue; }` etc...